# Docker info about images and container

Tags: docker

How can start a specific container created linked with my image? exec command? or another command?

And: Supposed to have more container to refer single image, what is the command to start a specific container with network?
The command `docker run` can start only image with network (`--net=host` for example), but I don't want run images, I want to run a specific container linked with my images. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) is purely for debugging purposing.
[`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) is what you want to start a container based on an image.

When you run a container, you do so based on an image and parameters like network.
Example:

```
docker run -itd --network=multi-host-network busybox
```

That being said, an existing running container can be attached to a network with the command [`docker network connect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/)

```
docker network connect [OPTIONS] NETWORK CONTAINER
```

Do a `docker ps` to get the ID or tag of your container.
Example:

```
docker network connect multi-host-network container1
```

---

Regarding the difference between image and containers:

[image: https://blog.newrelic.com/wp-content/uploads/docker-image-vs-containers.jpg]
(<sup>Source: "[The Modern Developer Workstation on MacOS with Docker](https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/06/20/docker-osx-mac/)", by [**Clay Smith**](https://twitter.com/smithclay)</sup>)

Comment: you said " docker run -itd --network=multi-host-network busybox " , but busybox is an image.. i've created more container with myimage for example. Container1 --> myImage.. Container2-> myImage.. I want to start Container1, not run myImage. maybe i explained myself wrong

Comment: Contaier1 is *already* started. You can attached it to the network with the last command I mention in the answer.

Comment: ok, i got it.. but command "run" start myImage with generic container id? in your example "busybox" is an image, can i insert a specific container id? I Would start a specific container linked to myImage and not run myImage

Comment: No, you can start it with a tag of your choosing: the doc is quite detailed on that.

Comment: it's not clear. Could you do an example? i've an image "myImage" and 2 container "container1 and container2" linked to myImage. I would to start container1 or container2 and use filesystem (myImage). or maybe i can create ONLY one container for Image.. I'm confused

Comment: You cannot start a container: if you ha EA container1 and 2, that means they are *already* started, possibly from the same image.

Comment: @Riccardo I have edited the answer with a picture illustrating the difference between image and container (and a link to the associated article). Is that clearer?

Comment: ok, thank you. But i can to decide a dock container that i want to run? I don't find anything commands about it. This is the question. I can run an image without to decide the container. I Would like to decide a specific container. It's possibile? for example, i've a container with django installed and another container with flask,both uses a linux image of course. I have to start only container with django framework. Thank you AGAIN :)

Comment: When you talk about container, you talk about what docker ps displays. Check it's output: you will see the container I'd, that you can use with docker command in order to target a specific container.